# How to access the file downloaded in the Internal Device memory

Tags: android, ftp-client

How can I access the file I downloaded in the Internal Memory of my Android device.
Meaning, I downloaded a file from the server on my device but I can't find it.
And how can I view it & access it "if I wan't to read the pdf file I downloaded for example" ??
I'm using the apache FTPClient API:
Here's is my code -

```
 public void DownloadServer(View view){
  try{
     filename = inputfld.getText().toString();
     fos=openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
     client.retrieveFile("/testing/"+filename, fos);
     fos.close();
     client.disconnect(); 
      }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
 }
```

Thanks alot in advance,

Comment: Without knowing what methods you use to download the file, it is difficult to help. Show some example code or explain the download procedure more fully.

Comment: I added a piece of my code hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

> How can I access the file I downloaded in the Internal Memory of my Android device.

Since you used `openFileOutput()` to write it, you read it with `openFileInput()`.

> Meaning, I downloaded a file from the server on my device but I can't find it.

You won't be able to see it, because you have no rights to view files on internal storage. The point of internal storage is for applications to store files, not for users to view files.

Comment: Ok, I get this point. So what will I have to do to be able to view the files as a user, especially that the android device I am testing on right now doesn't contain a SD card.

Comment: @Salma Hamed: Install an SD card. The point of internal storage is for applications to store files, not for users to view files.